# How to center this grid layout with css?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, center

I want to have the pinterest like items to be centered in the page.

my website: [www.keto.hu](http://www.keto.hu)
[image: picture]

Thank you!!

[image: images]

Comment: can u show us some code which relates to the element

Comment: wrap it in a div and center it with margin:0 auto.. have you done no googling?

Comment: You can right click and inspect element with Crome :)

Comment: but it already has 0 auto. (the div) should I wrap in one more div? 
<div id="grid" style=" overflow: hidden; height: 7896px;" class="isotope"> this one (this contains the items) already has margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 1210px` to the following rule.

```
#main-content #grid, #main-content #content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1210px;
}
```

For responsive `width` use `percentage`.

```
#main-content #grid, #main-content #content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 89.5%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: But I also don't want it fixed, I want it to be as wide as possible. Or should I add a lot of fixed widths for specific screen widths? That could be a solution but not as nice :) Thanks!

Comment: @skyli - The fixed `width` is for the `width` of the grid not the entire width. You have to give it a fixed `width` in order for `margin: 0 auto` to work.

Comment: yes but for example, when you have an 1920 pixel wide monitor and I want it all covered with these small cards. So then I need to make some screen size specific css's. But that would work :) If there is no better solution, then I'll do yours :) thanks!

Comment: @skyli - Then use `width: 89.5%;` instead.

Comment: that is not working :/ a fixed width works but somehow 89.5% is not

Comment: @skyli - Please define _"that is not working"_ it works fine for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/U1RHLMR.png

Comment: @skyli - Well, that's happeneing because your images are fixed `width`.

Comment: @skyli - Try `90%` or `90.5%` or `91%` instead. Or else use `@media` queries.

Comment: Thanks :) Then it is solved! :) thank you very much!:)